# Is it possible to add an attachment to a custom object before insert using the SalesForce Soap API?

Tags: c#, api, salesforce

I currently have a custom object, let's call this object myObject.

The object has these fields:

- Make - Text(20)
- Model - Text(20)
- StartTime - Date/Time
- End Time - Date/Time
- Country - Text(20)
- objContact - Lookup(Contact)*

*Note: the contact is set from a before insert trigger.

The requirement is to create an application to allow a user to create multiple myObjects and attach an image to each (up to 1MB).

Note: I have pushed an image to myObject using a Rich Text Area field, but this is approach limited to 32kb.

I am using the Salesforce Soap API (C#) with the following code (using inline methods for clarity):

```
public void Create(List<Cars> myCars)
{
    SforceService sforceService = new SforceService() { Timeout = 60000 };
    LoginResult result = sforceService.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    if (result.passwordExpired != true)
    {
        String authEndPoint = sforceService.Url;
        sforceService.Url = "result.serverUrl;
        sforceService.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
        sforceService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = result.sessionId;

        sObject[] myObjectArr = new sObject[myObjects.Count * 2];
        for (int i = 0, carCount = myCars.Count; i < carCount; i++)
        {        
            myObject__c myObj = new myObject__c();
            myObj.Make__c = myCars[i].make;
            myObj.Model__c = myCars[i].model;
            myObj.StartTime__c = myCars[i].startTime;
            myObj.EndTime__c = myCars[i].endTime;
            myObj.Country__c = myCars[i].country;

            //Convert Image to Byte[]:
            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                myCars[i].Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }

            Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment();
            myAttachment.Body = imageBytes;
            myAttachment.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            myAttachment.Name = "FileName";
            myAttachment.ParentId = myObj.id;

            myObjectArr[i] = myObj;
            myObjectArr[i + myCars.Count] = myAttachment;
        }
        sforceService.create(myObjectArr);
    }
}
```

The code executes properly, creating a new myObject for each Car Object passed into the function. However, because the temporary myObj has not been inserted into SFDC yet, it has no id. When the myAttachment.ParentId gets assigned, the myObj.id is null.

The function will be called with 1 - 2000 objects in the myCars list, so a non-bulkified approach will not be acceptable.

Is there any way to set the attachment's ParentId field to the myObj SFID during the Insert Operation?

The only approach I can think of is to create a temporary id (datetime + GUID) on each MyObj, and set the Attachment.Name to that temporary id (datetime + GUID), then create a trigger to associate the two after insert. Is there a better way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here is what worked:

```
public void Create(List<Cars> myCars)
{
    SforceService sforceService = new SforceService() { Timeout = 60000 };
    LoginResult result = sforceService.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    if (result.passwordExpired != true)
    {
        String authEndPoint = sforceService.Url;
        sforceService.Url = "result.serverUrl;
        sforceService.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
        sforceService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = result.sessionId;

        List<string> GUIDList = new List<string>();
        List<Attachment> AttachmentList = new List<Attachment>();

        sObject[] myObjectArr = new sObject[myObjects.Count];
        sObject[] myObjectArr_Attachments = new sObject[myObjects.Count];

        for (int i = 0, carCount = myCars.Count; i < carCount; i++)
        {   
            string tempGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
            GUIDList.add(tempGUID);

            myObject__c myObj = new myObject__c();
            myObj.Make__c = myCars[i].make;
            myObj.Model__c = myCars[i].model;
            myObj.StartTime__c = myCars[i].startTime;
            myObj.EndTime__c = myCars[i].endTime;
            myObj.Country__c = myCars[i].country;
            myObj.GUID__c = tempGUID;

            //Convert Image to Byte[]:
            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                myCars[i].Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }

            Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment();
            myAttachment.Body = imageBytes;
            myAttachment.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            myAttachment.Name = tempGUID;
            AttachmentList.add(myAttachment);

            myObjectArr[i] = myObj;
        }

        sforceService.create(myObjectArr);

        string GUIDListString = "( ";
        for ( int i = 0, listLen = GUIDList.Count; i < listLen; i++)
        {
            if (i < GUIDList.Count - 1)
            {
                 GUIDListString += string.Format("'{0}', ", GUIDList[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                 GUIDListString += string.Format("'{0}')", GUIDList[i]);
            }
        }


        string queryString = String.Format("SELECT id, GUID__c FROM myObj__c WHERE GUID__c IN {0}", GUIDListString);
        QueryResult myObjResult = sforceService.query(queryString);
        sObject[] sObjQuery = myObjResult.records;

        List<myObject__c> myObjs = new List<myObject__c>();

        foreach(sObject sObj in sObjQuery)
        {
             myObjs.Add((myObject__c)sObj);
        }

        for (int i = 0, attLen = AttachmentList.Count; i < attLen; i++)
        {
            foreach (myObject__c obj in myObjs)
            {
                if(AttachmentList[i].Name == obj.GUID__c)
                {
                    AttachmentList[i].ParentId = obj.Id;
                    sObjArr_Attachments[i] = AttachmentList[i];
                }
            }
        }
        SaveResult[] sr_att = sforceService.create(sObjArr_Attachments);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it one call, but you can split it up into just 2, one which inserts the list of Cars, once you have that result, you can then do a 2nd call to insert the list of attachments.

Comment: Thanks, I had to do the following: 1. Create GUID 2. Create myObj with GUID 3. Create Attachment with name=Guid 4. Add GUID to a list of Guids 5. Insert list of myObj 5. SOQL myObj IN GuidList 6. Add ID of result to each Attachment 7. Insert Attachments.

Comment: the save result returned by the create call includes the record Id of the newly created record, so you can then use that with your attachment records, you don't need all that other steps.

Comment: EDIT: I couldn't use the save result, as it doesn't have any information other than the id that was created. I wouldn't want to rely on the order of the save result for pairing.

Comment: the order of the result is well defined to match the order of records in the request, you can safely rely on it (thousands of other people already do)